# Decode XML returned by a webservice (< and > are replaced with &lt; and &gt)?

Tags: c#, .net, webservice-client

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to decode string to XML string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757019/how-to-decode-string-to-xml-string-in-c-sharp)

I'm calling a webservice which returns XML. If I'm using SOAP, all is fine, I get valid XML back. If however I use POST to get the return value, the XML arrives encoded as the content of the response. 
This means, all < and > are replaced with `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

Is there a way to convert the string back into valid XML? I don't want to use a RegEx or to replace manually since I'm sure that there are a couple of other characters that have been encoded besides the < and >.

Framework is .NET 3.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `HttpServerUtility.HtmlDecode(encodedString)` to return the decoded string.

Appropriate msdn link [HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwzhtkke%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

For some reason `HttpServerUtility.HtmlDecode` is not exist for me.

Try `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` to solve this problem.