# How to decode string to XML string in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I have a string (from a CDATA element) that contains description of XML.  I need to decode this string into a new string that displays the characters correctly using C#

Existing String:

```
&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?&gt;&lt;myreport xmlns="http://test.com/rules/client"&gt;&lt;admin&gt;&lt;ordernumber&gt;123&lt;/ordernumber&gt;&lt;state&gt;NY&lt;/state&gt;&lt;/report&gt;&lt;/myreport&gt;
```

String Wanted:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<myreport xmlns="http://test.com/rules/client">
<admin><ordernumber>123</ordernumber><state>NY</state></report></myreport>
```

Comment: but your existing string is *invalid*

Comment: @naveen: Surely that's just the _contents_ of the string...

Comment: @Jeff Mercado: was using linqpad to write an answer when i saw the string is invalid and `HtmlDecode` won't work as it accepts `string`. was merley pointing out that our OP needs to escape `"` too.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

1. [`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.htmldecode) from `System.Web`
2. [`WebUtility.HtmlDecode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.htmldecode) from `System.Net`

Answer (score 46):

You can use [System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.htmldecode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwzhtkke%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Useful if you don't want [System.Web](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web(v=vs.90).aspx) reference and prefer [System.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Comment: Thanks! This is really handy, as I want to target the .NET 4.0 Client Profile, but referencing System.Web would require me to target the full .NET 4.0 profile.

Answer (score 6):

As *Kirill* and *msarchet* said, you can use [`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode.aspx) from `System.Web`. It escapes pretty much anything correctly.

If you don't want to reference `System.Web` you might use some **trick** which supports all XML escaping but not HTML-specific escaping like `&eacute;`:

```
public static string XmlDecode(string value) {
    var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.LoadXml("<root>" + value + "</root>");
    return xmlDoc.InnerText;
}
```

You could also use a **RegEx** or simple `string.Replace` but it would only support basic XML escaping. Things like `&#x410;` or `&eacute;` are examples that would be harder to support.

Comment: I wouldn't parse XML/HTML with RegEx: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/

Comment: (I liked the XmlDocument-method though) +1

Answer (score 1):

`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(xmlString)` will solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use **HTML.Raw**. That way the markup is not encoded.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code to better explain your answer?

Answer (score -1):

You just need to replace the scaped characters with their originals.

```
string stringWanted= existingString.Replace("&lt;", "<")
                                                   .Replace("&amp;", "&")
                                                   .Replace("&gt;", ">")
                                                   .Replace("&quot;", "\"")
                                                   .Replace("&apos;", "'");
```

Comment: Well that is very strange. I've just [produced an example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vRfBTE) that I was expecting to demonstrate the problem, and it works precisely as desired. What makes it strange is that I *know* this exact situation is responsible for an XML parsing error in a codebase I maintain that I fixed *yesterday*. At least, I think it's exactly the same. I'll cancel the downvote and remove my original comment until I get a chance to check.

Answer (score -2):

You might also consider the static parse method from [XDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse(v=vs.110).aspx). I'm not sure how it compares to others mentioned here, but it seems to parse these strings well.

Once you get the resulting XDocument, you could turn around with ToString to get the string back:

```
string parsedString = XDocument.Parse("<My XML />").ToString();
```