# Replace &quot; with " in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my website I am preparing an array using datagrid items in c#, which works fine, however when I have some text in the grid which has `"` as value code automatically replaces it with `&quot;`

i have tried to replace `&quot;` with `"` as below, however its failing and replacing `&quot;` with `\"`

```
Array.Value += "|" + dgrFinal.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text.Replace
("amp;", "").Replace("&quot;","\"")
```

is there any way i can replace `&quot;` with ".

Can anyone please help me in this.....come on guys you are expert.

Comment: Why do want to replace `&quot;` with `\"`?

Comment: Has your `GridView` `AutoGenerateColumns=True`?

Comment: Hi, I want to replace &quot; with "

Comment: This sounds like a mismatch between encoded and non-encoded data; perhaps double-encoding. It would be better to find out *why it is there*, than to replace it...

Comment: AutoGenerateColumns is false

Comment: why don't you use `Server.HtmlDecode`

Comment: Are you _sure_ it's failing and replacing with `\"`, rather than you just _seeing_ `\"` in the debugger, which is how the debugger displays quotes in strings?

Comment: Thanks Rawling...you are correct ...in debugger it was showing as \" however in actual its working. Thanks for all help.

Comment: You can find the answer to your question here
[How to decode string to XML string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757019/how-to-decode-string-to-xml-string-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 12):

You can use `HttpUtility`. Here is an example.

```
using System.Web;
```

...

```
string value1 = "&lt;html&gt;";
string value2 = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(value1);
string value3 = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(value2);
Debug.WriteLine(value1);
Debug.WriteLine(value2);
Debug.WriteLine(value3);
```

This is the ouput:

```
&lt;html&gt;
<html>
&lt;html&gt;
```

I took the example from [here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/httputility).

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried

```
.Replace("&quot;", @"""")
```

Edit: outside of a GridView (I'm using LinqPad)

```
string xxx = "sd&quot;fd";
Console.WriteLine(xxx.Replace("&quot;", @""""));
```

returns:

> sd"fd

If it's still appearing as \" then the battle is with the gridView - I haven't used one for ages but I'd be tempted to try and get the data right before binding to the grid, rather than looping through the rows and cells afterwards.

Edit2:
I was going to say it could be the the debugger escaping the quotes but I'm days behind on this one. Good spot @Rawling. At least it's now solved :)

Comment: How is that functionally different than what was already done? I'm pretty sure that they compile to the same string literal. EDIT: (but now I'm doubting myself because I haven't had my morning coffee yet!)

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer, @Swanand: With the `@` marker for strings, two quotes is how you define a single quote.

Comment: its converting &quot; to \"

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net GridViewRow:

`row.Cells[3].Text.Trim().Replace("&quot;", @"""")`

**Before**: `&quot;Gasket 22&quot;&quot; rubber ventlation pipes&quot;`

**After**: "Gasket 22"" rubber ventlation pipes"