# Characters < and > converted to &lt; and &gt; during SOAP REQUEST C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, soap

I need some assistance. Am working with third party web service to send and receive SOAP requests & responses respectively. One of the requirement from the 3rd party web service is that when I send requests, they must be in a CDATA + XML. All to be passed as a string.

The thing is, when I am sending the requests, the characters `<` and `>` are converted to `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively, and as such I can't be able to send successful requests.

[image: Attached is a picture showing how the tags are converted]

Any person who can assist in figuring that out?

Comment: They're special characters in mark-up languages, they *have* to be escaped.

Comment: Alexander, Could you please demonstrate with sample code.

Comment: You already have sample code in your question: html is a mark-up language too and `&lt;` got changed into `<`

Comment: The thing is, I dont want < to be converted to &lt;

Comment: It's pretty hard to say what are you willing to do without having your code, but what happened here is that HTML characters got encoded. In c# there's a method for that: `HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode`. There's also `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`, which is reversing it, if you have place to hook in, maybe you could use it.

Comment: this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757019/how-to-decode-string-to-xml-string-in-c-sharp