# How to set xmlTag inside innerXml in c#?

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xpath

I am working on an application in which requirement is to replace specific word with a tag inside a line.

For example consider following line

```
became an accomplished singer, musician, and hymn writer 1
```

1 is replace with some text and final output should be like as shown below in xml

```
     <ln coord="25.78:338.56:318.35:346.89" page="1" height="574.98" left="25.78" 
top="338.56" font="CrimsonText-Roman" fontsize="12.5" fonttype="Embeded">
        became an accomplished singer, musician, and hymn writer in 
    <footnote id='1'>1 </footnote> </ln>
```

I have tried following code

```
Line.InnerXml.Replace("&lt;", "<").Replace("&gt;", ">");
```

But still get the following output in xml

```
 <ln coord="25.78:338.56:318.35:346.89" page="1" height="574.98" left="25.78" 
    top="338.56" font="CrimsonText-Roman" fontsize="12.5" fonttype="Embeded">
            became an accomplished singer, musician, and hymn writer in 
        &lt;footnote id='1'&gt;1 &lt;/footnote&gt; </ln>
```

How to get required output in xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was allready solved in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757019/how-to-decode-string-to-xml-string-in-c-sharp) post

> Look at  [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode.aspx)