# Decode a few times escaped XML characters in C#

Tags: c#, xml, character-encoding, decode

I have an input string with a few times escaped XML inner text. E.g.:

```
<anode>some &amp;quot;inner&amp;quot; text</anode>
```

I'd like to have (in a variable) value:

```
some "inner" text
```

How can I do it in C#?

I want the solution to handle triple-encoded cases (and N-encoded cases). I.e. `&amp;amp;quot;`
Not only `&quot` is interesting me, but any other encoded symbol (e.g. `lt, gt` etc).

Comment: Try using search...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757019/how-to-decode-string-to-xml-string-in-c-sharp

Then read the basics about "for", "while" or recursions (which would be too much in this case)

Comment: there is no valid n-time encoding defined `&amp;amp;quot;` is invalid, it should be `&amp;&amp;&quot;` You have to write a decoder on your own

Comment: Use `replace` on the `InnerXml` (a string value) and replace `&amp;quot;` with `&quot;` If all your entities are *double escaped* it can be okay to replace any `&amp;` with `&`. This manipulated string use to build a new document.

Comment: Btw: This often occurs when the entities are encoded by a self built `replace` based *engine*. Creating an XML with the appropriate tool should never bring back such bad encodings... So - if there is any chance - try to solve this when the XML is created.