# Can i replace "&lt;" with "<", "&gt;" with ">" before doc.save in xmldocument c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xmldocument

Let say i have this code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode school = doc.CreateElement("School");
school.Innertext = "<p>" + Welcome to the school "</p>";
doc.AppendChild(school);
doc.Save(filepath);
```

It will return this xml file:

```
<School>
&lt;p%gt;Welcome to the school&lt;/p%gt;
</School>
```

How do i replace &lt ; with "<", &gt ; with ">" before doc.save in xmldocument?

Comment: Don't do it manually it could be error prone.  Use inbuild classes like [HttpUtility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Here is a similar question on SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757019/how-to-decode-string-to-xml-string-in-c-sharp

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to achieve as result? (It would definitely be safer to set inner XML as XML rather than trying to hack something up)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov i would like to achieve this result:
<School>
<p>Welcome to the school</p>
</School>
can you give example on innerXml?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to decode string to XML string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757019/how-to-decode-string-to-xml-string-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @शेखर can you give coding example on HttpUtility based on my code?

Comment: @Jazb can you give coding example on HttpUtility based on my code?

Comment: I know that I should not answer (as there are [duplicates](https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23%20xdocument%20set%20innerxml%20site%3Astackoverflow.com)... I just can't pick one I like the best) and I know that suggesting to read the docs on InnerXml is not acceptable... sorry I can't help much here.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov i read the doc but have no idea on how to implement it. Thanks for your time tho :)