# SSIS Web Service Task returns a file file with "&lt;", &lt;/Value&gt; characters

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis, etl, ssis-2008

I have a simple ssis package what saves result from web service method to XML file. 
Connection OK, file creating, but contains `&lt;` and `&gt;` tags instead of `<` and `>` .

How I can replace this tags to correct? [image]

Comment: can you add more details? maybe a screenshot of the package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that you are passing the xml from the web service as a string *(Not recommended)*

you have to change the web method to return an `XmlDocument`, load the well-formed xml into it, and passed it back SSIS.

Or you can do a little workaround is to run a script after saving the xml file and replace `&lt;` with `<` and `&gt;` with `>`

**Useful Links**

- [Decode XML returned by a webservice (< and > are replaced with &lt; and &gt)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006020/decode-xml-returned-by-a-webservice-and-are-replaced-with-lt-and-gt)
- [How to decode string to XML string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757019/how-to-decode-string-to-xml-string-in-c-sharp)
- [Why are my "<br />" tags getting converted to "&lt;br /&gt;"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353718/why-are-my-br-tags-getting-converted-to-ltbr-gt)
- [SSIS 2005 mangling input XML from web service](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7c2c052e-c244-4f9b-ae03-87ddc6647d46/ssis-2005-mangling-input-xml-from-web-service?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

Comment: Thank You Hadi, I interesting in this method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006020/decode-xml-returned-by-a-webservice-and-are-replaced-with-lt-and-gt . Would be great if you can provide some example here.

Answer (score 0):

Also one of options

```
    Dim fileFirst As String = Dts.Variables("User::FullFilePath").Value.ToString()
    File.WriteAllText(fileFirst, File.ReadAllText(fileFirst).Replace("&lt;", "<"))

    Dim fileSecond As String = Dts.Variables("User::FullFilePath").Value.ToString()
    File.WriteAllText(fileSecond, File.ReadAllText(fileSecond).Replace("&gt;", ">"))

    Dim fileThird As String = Dts.Variables("User::FullFilePath").Value.ToString()
    File.WriteAllText(fileThird, File.ReadAllText(fileThird).Replace("&amp;", "&"))

    Dim fileFour As String = Dts.Variables("User::FullFilePath").Value.ToString()
    File.WriteAllText(fileFour, File.ReadAllText(fileFour).Replace("&quot;", "\"))

    Dim fileFive As String = Dts.Variables("User::FullFilePath").Value.ToString()
    File.WriteAllText(fileFive, File.ReadAllText(fileFive).Replace("&apos;", "'"))
```

using Script task -> VB